# Symbology for different years

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have an attribute field which contains Date data. The data is broken down like "3/14/2016". I would like to have different symbology for different years. When I go into the symbology tab within the layer properties and set the field that contains the date I do not have the option to set the symbology for each year. Instead it shows me a list of dates contained in the fields like the above example. How do I tell arcmap to only look at the year and not the month and day? So in the long run every feature with the same year has the same symbol?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a field containing only the Year by slicing the existing field, and then symbolize using that field.

Comment: Ohh my goodness. I don't know how I over looked this method. Thank you for the help! Pretty simple answer in the end!

Comment: Im glad to help!